# Paste special values and transpose into a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple rows.  I am trying to copying a selection one row at a time and paste (values and transposed) into a template spreadsheet.  I can open the blank template spreadsheet and select the data that I want to paste but am having a problem getting the data to paste values and transpose.

I am also having a problem saving the template somewhere new with a meaningful name.

Here is my code:

```
 Function CreateIndividualFiles(ash, individualTempPath, individualCompletedPath)

Do While ash.Cells(8 + n, 2) <> ""

    Dim xl0 As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
    
    Set xlw = xl0.Workbooks.Open(individualTempPath)
    
    ash.Range(Cells(8 + n, 2), Cells(8 + n, 49)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    xl0.Worksheets.Add
    
    xl0.ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    
    xl0.Workbook.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split\" & DeptDirName & "\" & departmentName & "\" & DeptFileName, fileFormat:=51
    
    
    xlw.Close
    
    Set xl0 = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing


n = n + 1
    
Loop
    

End Function
```

Comment: Can you show what the result is? And what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot do both paste just values and transpose with paste special.  I use the following to accomplish this:

```
Sub trnspEquat()
    For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.count
        For j = 1 To Selection.Columns.count
            ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, Selection.Columns.count + i).value = Selection.cells.(i, j).value
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will give you a start, it currently puts the value next to the existing data.  I will let you change it to put it on another sheet.

And before everyone starts yelling at me for using Selection and ActiveCell.  The idea behind this is to highlight a range then using a keystroke assigned to this macro, the data is transposed.